# Spring data CrudRepo and Spring Batch ... too many classes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

It seems my ETL project is turning into a lot of classes. I'm using spring data crudrepository along with spring batch to fetch and load data.

1. I have 18 tables
2. I have 18 entities, one for each table
3. I have 18 repository interfaces, one for each entity
4. I have 18 services, one for each repository
5. On spring batch side: I have a Reader, Processor, and Write class for each table (54 classes).

This is turning into a lot of classes and lot of tedious coding. Is there a way to make use of a generics with any of these classes or simply the structure?

Comment: you have to have those classes.

Comment: you don't need  **18 services, one for each repository**. you can have multiple repositories in one service.

Comment: If the entities are related, some of the repository can be omitted. Usually    you can access all from few "main" entities.

Comment: ItemReaders and ItemWriters are very similar. Been trying to create an itemFactory to reduce the amount of classes for the batch process